# What's the simplest way to be able to cast Suggestion starting from a 5th level Human Fighter?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization, character-advancement

I have a battlemaster fighter who, for flavor reasons, I would love if he could cast the spell "Suggestion". He's level 5 in fighter at the moment, and since I have a level-up in my near future, I'm looking for a path towards this spell.

It's for a low-magic community-style game, so magic items aren't likely (not to mention, may not have the same DM twice in a row!). Multiclassing is allowed (artificer is not), all my stats are above 13 except Strength (10) and Intelligence (11) thanks to Non-Variant Human!

I've already looked at taking the "Fey-Touched" feat at level 6, but as "Suggestion" is a level 2 spell, it won't do enough. Likewise, as far as I can tell, multi-classing Sorcerer or Cleric won't help me achieve this without an additional two levels.

Is there anyway I can get to the "Suggestion" spell sooner?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what you can do? For example: are magic items (such as scrolls of rings of spell storing) an option? Is multiclassing allowed, and, if so, what are your stats? How often do you want to be able to cast *suggestion*? Is the Eldritch Knight Fighter subclass an option? Is your race already locked in place?

Comment: Realizing now those last two question are *probably* answered since you're already a 5th level Battle Master, but I'll ask them anyway, just in case

Comment: It's for a low-magic community-style game, so magic items aren't likely (not to mention, may not have the same DM twice in a row!). Multiclassing is allowed (artificer is *not*), all my stats are above 13 except Strength (10) and Intelligence (11) thanks to Non-Variant Human!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think **there is no faster way than spending three levels in multi-classing unless you can get DM buy-in** or use a magic item like the helm of telepathy.

The simplest solution might be to get a **[helm of telepathy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/helm-of-telepathy)**, it is an uncommon item, so it might be possible to get this even in a relatively low-magic campaign, in a major metropolis.

Barring that, the various feats that let you pick a spell (like *fey touched* or *magic initiate*) only give you first level spells as your pick, so they won't work.

The shortest route I can think of how you can do this innately is picking up three levels in a class like *sorcerer* or *warlock*, that has the spell on their list.

If you want to go that way, warlock might be a good option for you as a fighter, as you can pick a hexblade which can reinforce your prowess as a melee fighter with spells like *shield*, *wrathful smite*, the *hexblade's curse* and access to *hex* all from level one, so you are not wasting two levels just to bridge towards *suggestion*, without getting something out of them that works for what you already do. Sorcerer might also work; Wizard is probably not as good given your low intelligence score.

As [DragonOfFlame's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197152/whats-the-simplest-way-to-be-able-to-cast-suggestion-starting-from-a-5th-level/197166#197166) states, you might also be able to change your subclass retroactively, and get there within two levels, again this only works with your DM's approval.

Lastly, in addition to published rules, if your DM is willing to work with you, you could work out a feat with them that allows you to cast the spell 2-3 times a day, for example Charisma bonus times could work. The power value of being able to cast Suggestion once a day is worth about 3 points on [Detect Balance](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=0), while the value of a full feat or Ability Score Improvement is 8 points. Of course, such homebrew is not an official way.

Comment: Both of your suggestions are what OP already listed and dismissed. I'm not sure how that's really helpful.

Comment: If they cannot use magic items, then there is no faster way (unless there is one I don't know of). That may not be what they look for, but it is the answer to their question.

Comment: @NautArch, thanks, good point. I reordered it.

Comment: Interestingly to note, in the Playtest rules for D&D Next, right to the end, there were 3 more feats, granting a 2nd, 3rd and 4th level spell once per day, with the only prerequisite of having the previous feat in the "chain". I don't know why they were cut, but would guess because compared to other feats, they were relatively weak for the investment needed.

Answer (score 4):

### You could use the TCE customization rules to change your subclass

The fastest way to get suggestion as a fifth level fighter would be to change your subclass, to an Eldritch Knight. Fortunately, TCE allows this, saying:

> With your DM's approval, you can change your subclass when you would normally gain a new subclass feature. If you decide to make this change, choose another subclass that belongs to your class and replace all your old subclass features with the features of the new subclass that are for your new level and lower.

You would have to wait until 7th level (unless your DM hand waved that), but that would still be a level sooner than you would get it otherwise. Once your character became an Eldritch Knight, you would be able to take *suggestion* as one of your spells.

Answer (score 0):

### Change your race to Yuan-Ti

While this is a much harder option to achieve (and may even be unwanted), the up-to-date version of Yuan-Ti from (Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse) gains the ability to cast "Suggestion" starting at third level.

While this is obviously a more difficult feat to accomplish, it solves the issue without needing to multiclass or spend a feat at all. (Though it brings its own share of cons as well)

Comment: "While this is obviously a more difficult feat to accomplish" I'm not aware of *any* way to accomplish this within the rules except for a *wish* and a generous DM. The question seems to be looking for feasible methods within the grasp of the character they already made, so an answer really needs to actually outline the method proposed, so we can vote on the method as well as the resulting feature.

Comment: Given that the other, upvoted, answers also have "Work with the DM" as core parts of the answer, I do not see how this is any different. This method also happens to be what I wound up going with -- which, yes, required buy-in from the DM as my character "discovered" his Yuan-Ti heritage -- and my self-answer is merely annotating my personal solution in the hope that it is useful to others (who might be starting from level 1).